# How create 2 arrays from a multiline textbox for each row in C#? Then I need to plot in a graph those arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, graph, textbox

I have this multiline textbox:

14:33:29,   831

14:33:30,   834

14:35:1,    830

14:35:2,    833

I need to create 2 arrays:
first to contain data from left (14:33:29,14:33:30,14:35:1,14:35:2) and the second contain data from the right (831,834,830,833).
My textbox data are splitted by ",\t".
Data from left is DateTime type, and from right is integer.
Then I want to make a line graph in C# with those 2 arrays.
Can anyone help me, please?

I used this but just the first parameter is displayed.

string[]str = textBox3.Text.Split(',');

```
        foreach (string row in str)
        {
           
            textBox2.Text = str[0];
        }
```

Comment: I have a big project and this part give me headaches, I try some codes but nothing works, please don't be rude.

Comment: at least consider to post some more info and code examples with what you have tried, it looks like just parsing those strings will not help

Comment: Why not use something more upto the task, like a datagrid?

Comment: I use textbox because my data entry is from an external sensor which store data in text file and then transfer in textbox.

Comment: What I need is just figure it out how to parse this textbox, all rows, in just 2 arrays to use them later in my graph.

Comment: "Then I want to make a line graph in C# with those 2 arrays." Can you pls explain what it means?

Comment: For me it's unclear if you start with a list of string or the splitted version. And if you question is how to get the correct value . Or if you are looking for a the Chart control. And if you are looking a chart control, what framework are you using? winform? wpf?

Comment: here is a simple demo of parsing. https://dotnetfiddle.net/29efHo

Comment: To put first array in x axis value and second array in y axis value. But I am looking for parsing from a textbox multiline, not how to make graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it was tested in visual studio:

```
var s =
@"14:33:29, 831

  14:33:30, 834

  14:35:1, 830

  14:35:2, 833";
  
var strArr = s.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\n", ";")
.Split(";",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(a => a.Length>3).ToArray();

    var len=strArr.Length;
    var arr1= new string[len] ;
    var arr2 = new string[len];

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        var arr = strArr[i].Trim().Split(",");
        if (arr.Length == 2)
        {
            arr1[i] = arr[0];
            arr2[i] = arr[1];
        }
    }
```

result

```
arr1= {"14:33:29","14:33:30","14:35:1","14:35:2"};
arr2 ={"831","834","830","833"};
```

Comment: This is a very good code but I have the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: @xmi you string must be different from string you posted.

Comment: I have a textbox which data entry is not fixed, I need to parse  data from textbox. How can I change the code for this?

Comment: @xmi I updated my answer with more robust algorithm. Pls try again and let me know.

Comment: Thank you very very much, now works perfectly. Your code works exactly for what I want. Thank you!!